# Should I use a Guid and Guid.Empty or a nullable Guid?

Tags: c#, nullable, language-features, is-empty

I have certain scenarios (e.g. a custom class to hold Sql parameters) in which a variable may or may not be required. Traditionally I have always defined these being of type `Guid?` and used `myGuid.HasValue` to check for a valid value before using.

Of course in practice I could also use regular `Guid`s and perform the check for valid value with `myGuid == Guid.Empty`.

For readability I prefer the first usage as it feels cleaner but I would appreciate it if someone could advise on whether one of these methods is *better* (faster, quicker or more correct) than the other?

Comment: If it's not required, it will never be used?

Comment: Not never, but for example, an object with a `Guid` as an id field would not have this field populated until it had been persisted to a database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the parameter can be null on the T-Sql side, then I think `Guid?` is a more *natural* fit. Especially when used with ADO.NET parameterized queries, nullable types are conveniently translated to `DBNull.Value` when their value is `null`. If you were to use `Guid.Empty` to indicate null, then you'd need to check for that condition and explicitly pass `DBNull.Value` to your command/query. E.g.:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@guid", myNullableGuid)
```

vs.

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@guid", 
    myGuid == Guid.Empty ? DBNull.Value : myGuid)
```

There is virtually no performance difference between the two alternatives, otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

I think that approach with `Guid?` is much more better. It just a coincidence that a default value of `Guid` whuch is equal to `Guid.Empty` has no real usage and can be treated as `null` value. For example, `int` or `bool` default values are used without any distinction with other values.
So, IMHO, you should use `Guid?` to stay consistent.

Answer (score 1):

I usually use declaring like the followings:

```
Guid? objGuidStudent = null;
objGuidStudent = Students.FindByName('Oscar');
Classrooms.Add(x, y, z, objGuidStudent);
```

It works perfectly, either with or without NULL value.